# Vue js, Property or method "showExplaination" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to do a website using Vue js and I have a problem with a @click that don't find the function showExplaination().

I have the following error :  **[Vue warn]: Property or method "showExplaination" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.**

```
<div class="vue">

    <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="showExplaination">
            Show explaination                    
    </button>
    
    <div v-show="explaination">Explaination</div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript code

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '.vue',
    data: {
        explaination: false
    },
    method: {
        showExplaination: function() {
            this.explaination = !this.explaination;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you're missing the `s` in `method` it should be `methods:{`

Comment: Exactly what Boussadjra is saying

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot!